# Super Simple CSS Issue

Tags: html, css

Hi guys we have a site here: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/

And i am trying to change this hover part here:

[image]

I tried to target this:

```
.main-color-1-bg, 
.main-color-1-bg-hover:hover, 
input[type=submit], 
table:not(.shop_table)>thead, 
table:not(.shop_table)>tbody>tr:hover>td,
table:not(.shop_table)>tbody>tr:hover>th, 
header .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, 
header .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, header .multi-column > .dropdown-menu li.menu-item:hover, 
header .multi-column > .dropdown-menu .menu-column li.menu-item:hover,     
.un-icon:hover, 
.dark-div .un-icon:hover, 
.woocommerce-cart .shop_table.cart thead tr, 
.uni-addtocart .add-text, 
.event-classic-item .item-thumbnail:hover a:before, 
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page.active span, .owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-page:hover span, .course-list-table>tbody>tr:hover>td, .course-list-table>tbody>tr:hover>th, .project-item:hover .project-item-excerpt, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:after, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus:after, .topnav-sidebar #lang_sel_click ul ul a:hover, div.bbp-submit-wrapper .button, .topnav-sidebar #lang_sel ul ul a:hover{
color: red;
}
```

But it changes the whole color of the menu to red. How can I change the color of that hover scroll under the menu without affecting the other elements?

Please help!

Comment: See to to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can change the color of that pseudo element:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:after, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus:after {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And remove `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:after, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus:after,` lines the css selector you tried to change. This will decouple them.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the results]

Answer (score -1):

A simple answer for a simple question.

It's a common practice to place those kind of hover states as pseudo elements. When you are using your inspector, check for these elements further towards the bottom of the css rules.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus:after {
    background-color: red; /*or whatever colour you wish*/
}
```

Please don't forget to mark correct answers!

Hope this helps.

Comment: If there is something wrong with my answer I would really appreciate some feedback, thanks.